# Java class file to other format conversion, how many are there

Tags: java, class, cross-compiling

We all know that, for `android OS`, Dalvik is the VM.

Dalvik converts normal `Java` **.class** files to **.dex** files.

Similarly how many VMs are there and what are the formats each of them converts to?

Can we compile our own `java.exe` VM which will do our own **.class** file?

Does `Sun/Oracle` provided the source code for `javac.exe`, `java.exe`... etc? as it is an open source? Thanks in advance for Help

Comment: Yes, the OpenJDK project provides sources for the Java tools.

Answer (score 2):

Open JDK and JVM sources are available.

http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ (for open jdk javac)